# convert and optimize SQL Query to Active Record query in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, arel

How do i re-write this SQL query in Active Record query in rails

```
sqlQuery = "SELECT real_estate_agent_assignment_statuses.assignment_status, 
COUNT(developer_referrals.id) AS rea_count FROM 
real_estate_agent_assignment_statuses LEFT OUTER JOIN developer_referrals ON 
developer_referrals.real_estate_agent_assignment_status_id = 
real_estate_agent_assignment_statuses.id AND developer_referrals.project_id =
 1 AND developer_referrals.developer_staff_id IN (266) WHERE 
real_estate_agent_assignment_statuses.assignment_status IN ('Pending 
Eligibility Check', 'Completed Eligibility Check') AND 
real_estate_agent_assignment_statuses.deleted_at IS NULL GROUP BY 
real_estate_agent_assignment_statuses.assignment_status, 
real_estate_agent_assignment_statuses.rank ORDER BY 
real_estate_agent_assignment_statuses.rank ASC"
```

Answer (score 0):

My SQL is rusty but I think this will get you started.

```
sql_query1 = RealEstateAgentAssignmentStatus.joins(:developer_referrals)
                                            .where(:assignment_status => ['Pending Eligibility Check', 'Completed Eligibility Check'])
                                            .group(:assignment_status)
                                            .order(:rank)
                                            .all
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods

Answer (score 0):

With the right [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) and relationships set up you can do almost anything.

First step is to define the relationships and scopes.  I'm only guessing what your relationships are, but even if totally different the below code should roughly show how it all works:

```
class DeveloperReferral < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :staff_member

  scope :with_project, ->(project) {
    # merging allows you to define conditions on the join
    joins(:project).merge( Project.where(id: project) )
  }

  scope :with_staff_member, ->(staff_member) {
    # merging allows you to define conditions on the join
    joins(:staff_member).merge( StaffMember.where(id: staff_member) )
  }
end

class RealEstateAgentAssignmentStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :developer_referrals

  scope :with_status, ->(status) { where(status: status) }
  scope :not_deleted, -> { where(deleted_at: nil) }

  scope :with_project, ->(project) {
    # merging allows you to define conditions on the join
    joins(:developer_referrals).merge(
        DeveloperReferral.with_project(project)
      )
  }

  scope :with_staff_member, ->(staff_member) {
    # merging allows you to define conditions on the join
    joins(:developer_referrals).merge(
        DeveloperReferral.with_staff_member(staff_member)
      )
  }
end
```

Then you can build up your query using the scopes.

```
project = Project.find(1)
staff_members = project.staff_members

statuses =
  RealEstateAgentAssignmentStatus
    .with_project(project)
    .with_staff_member(staff_members)
    .with_status([
        'Pending Eligibility Check',
        'Completed Eligibility Check',
      ])
    .not_deleted
    .order(
        # we use `arel_table` so that SQL uses the namespaced column name
        RealEstateAgentAssignmentStatus.arel_table(:rank),
      )
```

And then you can do your group/count:

```
status_counts =
  statuses
    .group(
        # we use `arel_table` so that SQL uses the namespaced column name
        RealEstateAgentAssignmentStatus.arel_table(:assignment_status),
        RealEstateAgentAssignmentStatus.arel_table(:rank),
      )
    .count(:id)
```